# How to determine maximum storage capacity for indexedDb

Tags: html, indexeddb

I would like to make an offline web application and i want it to use `indexeddb`.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/quota-research/

I see that now, all browers implement indexedDb.

```
http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb
```

Do you guys see any problem in my approach?

i see that indexedDb will throw an error called 'QuotaExceededError', once it is out of memory.I am not sure if this is true for all browsers and circumstances or not, can anybody confirm that it is?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMException

if you scroll downand check QuoteExceededError it says it is experimental and should not be used in production, but it was there back in 2013.